# How to set the text of AppCompatTextView through its fields' set method, cuz it's not working now

Tags: android, field

I've been trying to make a util class, just like BeanUtil kinda things, it's about android's RecycleView, it can provide a template for RecycleView.ViewHolder, so that can suit for every class that extends RecycleView.ViewHolder, anyway, I got an issue, I was trying to set the text of AppCompatTextView through its fields' set method, it didn't work, here is my trying:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    System.out.println("holder");
    System.out.println(holder);
    Field[] fields = holder.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    try {
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(field.getName());
            System.out.println(field.getGenericType());
            System.out.println(field.getType());
            System.out.println(field.get(holder));
            Field[] fields1 = FieldUtils.getAllFields(field.get(holder).getClass());
            for (Field field1 : fields1) {
                field1.setAccessible(true);
                if (field1.getName().equals("mText")) {
                   System.out.println(field1.get(field.get(holder)));
                   System.out.println(new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(list.get(position))).optString(field.getName()));
                   field1.set(field1.get(field.get(holder)), new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(list.get(position))).optString(field.getName()));
```

here is output:

```
I/System.out: holder
    ViewHolder{7532fca position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
    last
    class android.widget.TextView
    class android.widget.TextView
I/System.out: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{737153b V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f080060 app:id/last}
    123222222222222222222222222222
I/System.out: 123456
I/System.out: who
    class android.widget.TextView
    class android.widget.TextView
I/System.out: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{18e3458 V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0800d4 app:id/who}
    123222222222222222222222222222
I/System.out: 123
```

and here is the ViewHolder:

```
public class MsgHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView who,last;
    public MsgHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.who = itemView.findViewById(R.id.who);
        this.last = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last);
    }
}
```

the output `123222222` is the text of TextView I set it in the xml, so,
as you can see, it can be get, but it just cannot be set, I was quite wondering. hope someone can help me out, really appreciate

Comment: you  `onBindViewHolder` snippet seems to be incomplete. where are you trying to set the text?

Comment: the last line I put up there in the `onBindViewHolder`, I want to set the text of TextView in the ViewHolder, I want it to adapt every customized class that extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, sorry for got you confused, hope I make some sence here

Comment: @MehranBehbahani, (ps: I forgot to mention you)